# python text conversion into Pig Latin

Tags: python

I need a python program for converting an input sentence into Pig Latin which has 2 rules:

1. If a word begins with a consonant all consonants before the first vowel are moved to the end of the word and the letters "ay" are then added to the end. e.g. "coin" becomes "oincay" and "flute" becomes "uteflay".
2. If a word begins with a vowel then "yay" is added to the end. e.g."egg" becomes "eggyay" and "oak" becomes "oakyay".

I have written this program so far:

```
string = input('String: ')

if string[0].upper() in 'BCDFGJKLMNPQSTVXZHRWY':

    print(string.replace(string[0],'') + string[0]+'ay')

if string[0].upper() in 'AEIOUY':
    print(string + 'yay')
#vowels = [each for each in
```

but this only works for one word(whereas i need the whole sentence), and the first part only replaces the first consonant, not all (whereas I need to replace all consonants before the first vowel)

Answer (score 0):

We can try using a regex replacement with a callback function:

```py
inp = "coin flute egg oak"
output = re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m: re.sub(r'([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+)(\w+)', r'\2\1ay', m.group()) if not re.search(r'^[AEIOUaeiou]', m.group()) else m.group() + 'yay', inp)
print(output)  # oincay uteflay eggyay oakyay
```

Comment: Should be `uteflay`

Comment: @JLPeyret I have updated my answer per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your input fetches the user input but string[0] refers only to the first char in the string. You need to use the .split() method to split the string into words and loop thru those words. However, now that you do this, you want to print it onto 1 line. Therefore, change the end parameter in print to something like a space.

try something like this:

```
sentance = input('String: ').split()
for word in sentance: # loop thru each word
    if word[0].upper() in 'BCDFGJKLMNPQSTVXZHRWY':
        print(word.replace(word[0],'') + word[0]+'ay', end = " ")
    elif word[0].upper() in 'AEIOUY':
        print(word + 'yay', end = " ")
print() # just to skip to a new line once its done
```

I modified the variable names for clarity. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help. But take the word 'the' as example. It needs to put all the consonants before the first vowel at the end of the word. so 'the' would become 'eth'. however, it only puts the first consonant 't' at the end, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the first vowel and then take case 1 or 2 depending on if that was past first char (0-indexed) or not.

```
def porcus(sin):
    vowels = set("aeiouy")

    for vowel1, ch in enumerate(sin.lower()):
        #identify first vowel - `ch in "aeiouy"` would work too.
        if ch in vowels:
            break
    else:
        return f"{sin}ay"

    if not vowel1:
        #starts with vowel
        return f"{sin}yay"
    
    #take from vowel position to end, add start before and ay
    res = sin[vowel1:] + sin[:vowel1] + "ay"
    
    return res


inps = "coin flute egg oak The" 
exps = "oincay uteflay eggyay oakyay eThay"

dataexp = zip(
        inps.split(),exps.split()
)

for inp, exp in dataexp:
    got = porcus(inp)
    msg = f"{str(inp):100.100} \n  exp :{exp}:\n  got :{got}:\n"
    if exp == got:
        print(f"✅! {msg}")
    else:
        print(f"❌!  {msg}")
```

#### output:

```
✅! coin                                                                                                 
  exp :oincay:
  got :oincay:

✅! flute                                                                                                
  exp :uteflay:
  got :uteflay:

✅! egg                                                                                                  
  exp :eggyay:
  got :eggyay:

✅! oak                                                                                                  
  exp :oakyay:
  got :oakyay:

✅! The                                                                                                  
  exp :eThay:
  got :eThay:
```

You can plug in `xkcd` too.  I assumed you'd want `xkcday`.

re. whole sentence `print(" ".join([porcus(w) for w in sentence.split()]))` oughta work.

Comment: @hugostiglitz well, when you've confirmed it works, you can accept it.  hint hint.